# What the different between React$Element and ReactElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, flow-typed

I am trying to use flow with ReactJS. I need to add type to prop children. The article ([Flow + React](https://flow.org/en/docs/frameworks/react/)) does not say anything about it.

I'v found a lot of examples which use ReactElement ([e.g](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1964)). But flow says `identifier ReactElement. Could not resolve name`. I use React$Element<*> and it works.

The question. What the different between React$Element and ReactElement? And where can I find information about React$Element? Where does flow search type definitions.

Answer (score 2):

`React$Element` currently lives in the 'react.js' library file bundled with [Flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/02e59773c2941fc05492d551c59f4929e12908d0/lib/react.js#L109-L119):

```
/**
 * Type of a React element. React elements are commonly created using JSX
 * literals, which desugar to React.createElement calls (see below). The type
 * parameterization of React$Element mimics that of ReactClass (see above).
 */
declare class React$Element<Config> {
  type: ReactClass<Config>;
  props: $PropsOf<Config>;
  key: ?string;
  ref: any;
}
```

It might eventually move to the new [flowtype/flow-typed repo](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) as the Flow team mentioned in their [Introducing Flow Typed](https://flow.org/blog/2016/10/13/Flow-Typed/) blog post. If you need definitions for libraries you install from NPM, 'flow-typed' is where to look.